Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata) : newdata has 0 rows when using superClass()
I am working on classifying an image (.tif) using the code below. I have encountered an error

Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata): newdata has 0 rows

Anything I am not doing right?
#libraries
library(sf)
library(RStoolbox)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(terra)
library(caret)
library(e1071)

#Load image
kalomo2022<- brick("Kalomo_2022.tif")

#Train data
train <- sf::read_sf("Train_Kal_only2022_1.shp")
train_1 <- as(train, "Spatial") #to change it from sf to spatial


#conducting the classification
sc_kalomo2022<- superClass(kalomo2022, model = "rf", trainData = train_1,  
                           responseCol = "id", mode = "classification",
                           nsamples = 10000, nSamplesV = 10000, 
                           polygonBasedCV = T, kfold = 5, minDist = 1, 
                           trainPartition = .8, na.rm = T, predict=T, 
                           predType = "raw")


Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R (I presume?) forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

@Adiraan, thanks for the indication on the programming language. I am currently working on this using R.

I am unable to reproduce your error. Please visit How to make a great R reproducible example.
